# Asp.Net Identity update to 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a problem updating Asp.Net Identity to v2. I followed the instruction from   [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/updating-asp-net-applications-from-asp-net-identity-1-0-to-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)  and evertything was fine, but the code that the migration generated is not the same.

Instead of AlterColumn ot DropColumn commands in my Up method I have code to create all my columns again, and in the Down method the code is to drop all the columns and indexes. That's why when I try to update my database there is a conflict when trying to recreate a table, that already exists.

Here is part of the generated code:

```
public partial class Update1 : DbMigration
        {
            public override void Up()
            {
                CreateTable(
                    "dbo.Analyses",
                    c => new
                        {
                            AnalysisID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                            CompanyID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                            //...
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.AnalysisID);
                CreateTable(
                    "dbo.Companies",
                    c => new
                        {
                            CompanyID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                            Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                            //...
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.CompanyID);
                // continues with all the table I have in the database
        }
      public override void Down()
            {
                DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
                DropForeignKey("dbo.Contracts", "LastEditUserID", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
                //...
                DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
                DropIndex("dbo.Contracts", new[] { "LastEditUserID" });
                DropIndex("dbo.Contracts", new[] { "InputUserID" });
                DropIndex("dbo.Contracts", new[] { "FileID" });
                //...
                DropTable("dbo.UserSettings");
                DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
                DropTable("dbo.ContractTypes");
                DropTable("dbo.Contracts");
                //...
             }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It didn't change the context did it?  It looks like it's treating the database as an empty DB.

Comment: What had to be changed in the context? It is the same as before the update

Comment: The instructions that I followed (went looking for them - can't find them) had me adding `throwIfV1Schema: false` to the context constructor.

Comment: I already did this

`public class LaborHealthEntities : IdentityDbContext<User>, ILaborHealthEntities
    {
        public LaborHealthEntities()
            : base("name=DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }`

Comment: What does the configuration.cs look like (in the migrations folder)?

Comment: `internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<LaborHealth.Web.Models.Entities.LaborHealthEntities>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(LaborHealth.Web.Models.Entities.LaborHealthEntities context)
        { //Some comments here }
}`

Comment: The tables dbo.Analyses and dbo.Companies are not part of the ASP.NET Identity 1 or 2.  During migration it is going to look at the connection string for the project to compare an existing database against the model defined by your entities in your code.  It looks like the database it compared did not have the schema for ASP.NET Identity v1 in it. Did you have the correct project selected and was the connection string pointing to the correct place?  Did you ever login with a user in the original version with ASP.NET Identity v1 to create the database?

Comment: @KevinJunghans thanks alot! I don't have the schema and I didn't knew that it compares to it.